# How to find arguments on Amazon site using webdriver in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating new automation app that uses Amazon site, having troubles to find some of the elements.
The page structure changes so it has to be dynamic over different Amazon accounts.

This is for our company server, running using visual studio 2017.

```
fiftElement = browseDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("a-popover a-dropdown a-dropdown-common a-declarative"));

fiftElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(@data-value,'RO_CR-DEFECTIVE')]")).Click();
```

as you could [1]: https://gyazo.com/0f4c52f4eccdd9d9b15379cf1dee7c42
I'm trying to click on a certain box from a dropdown, where the order of the boxes could change and there is no difference between them but the "data-value" and the text

I would like to simply find the "Item is defective " box and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the dropdown elements in a list and iterate over it to check if it contains the `Item defective` text and as soon as you get the text you can click on that option.

If there is only one dropdown list with the class `a-dropdown-item` then you can fetch the list of webelement simple by using:

```
List<WebElement> dropdownElements = browseDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName('a-dropdown-item'));
```

And if there are multiple dropdowns with the same className then you can fetch this particular dropdown list by using the following xpath:

```
List<WebElement> dropdownElements = browseDriver.FindElements(By.Xpath('//div[contains(@class,'a-popover-inner')]//li[@class='a-dropdown-item']//a'));
```

And then you can add the logic for matching the text like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dropdownElements.Count; i++) {
        if (dropdownElements.get(i).getText().contains("Item defective")) {
            dropdownElements.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```